# Powershell: return filename with highest number

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames

Suppose I have a list of filenames like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "Antarctica Data *.xls"

Antarctica Data 03625516.xls
Antarctica Data 84327262.xls
Antarctica Data 16374175.xls
Antarctica Data 12804427.xls
Antarctica Data 17477809.xls
Antarctica Data 60943758.xls
Antarctica Data 93962083.xls
Antarctica Data 74412097.xls
Antarctica Data 81562648.xls
Antarctica Data 58371936.xls
```

How can I use Powershell to return a string of the filename with highest number?

```
Antarctica Data 93962083.xls
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the names only differ by the numbers, all you need to do is sort them and then get the last one:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "Antarctica Data *.xls" |
Sort-Object |
Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name
```

Or, more concisely:

```powershell
(gci "Antarctica Data *.xls" | sort)[-1].Name
```

Output:

> Antarctica Data 93962083.xls

Comment: +1 Be aware that this answer only works if all the numbers are 8 digits long. Ex. 99 will be sorted as higher then 98765432. Judging by the sample, it should be alright. Just wanted to mention it for future readers. :)