# Powershell Return the highest 4 Digit Number Found in a String Pattern - Search Word Documents

Tags: regex, powershell, ms-word

I am trying to return the **highest** 4 digit number found in string pattern, in a set of documents.

**String Pattern: 3 Letters dash 4 Digits**

The word documents contain within them a document identifier code such as below.

**Sample Files:**

Car Parts.docx   >      CPW - 2345

CarHandles.docx  >      CPW - 8723

CarList.docx >          CPA - 9083

I have referenced sample code  that I am trying to adapt. I am not a VBA or powershell programmer - so I may be wrong in what I am trying to do?

I am happy to look at alternatives - on a Windows platform.

I have referenced this to get me started

http://chris-nullpayload.rhcloud.com/2012/07/find-and-replace-string-in-all-docx-files-recursively/

[PowerShell: return the number of instances find in a file for a search pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507110/powershell-return-the-number-of-instances-find-in-a-file-for-a-search-pattern)

[Powershell: return filename with highest number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916918/powershell-return-filename-with-highest-number)

```
$list = gci "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\SearchFiles" -Include *.docx -Force -recurse
foreach ($foo in $list) {

$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $False

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("$foo")
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 

$Pat1 = [regex]'[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}'   # Find the regex match 3 letters  followed by 4 numbers eg     HGW - 1024

$findtext= "$Pat1"

 $highestNumber = 

 # Find the highest occurrence of this pattern found in the documents searched - output to text file or on screen

Sort-Object |                   # This may also be wrong -I added it for when I find the pattern
Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name


<#   The below may not be needed  - ?

$ReplaceText = ""

$ReplaceAll = 2
$FindContinue = 1
$MatchFuzzy = $False
$MatchCase = $False
$MatchPhrase = $false
$MatchWholeWord = $True
$MatchWildcards = $True
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False
$Forward = $True
$Wrap = $FindContinue
$Format = $False

$objSelection.Find.execute(
    $FindText,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
    $ReplaceText,
    $ReplaceAll
  }

}
#>
```

I appreciate any advice on how to proceed -

Comment: The best way to proceed, is to determine what exactly is not working, find out why and then fix that. If you have any *specific* problems getting this up and running, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I could not find the pattern $Pat1 = [regex]'[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}' to begin with - I have added notes to where i am stuck on the code.

Comment: btw, what Powershell version are you on?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I believe 5, I am on windows 10 - I have power shell ISE as Well. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# This library is needed to extact zip archives. A .docx is a zip archive
# .NET 4.5 or later is requried
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

# This function gets plain text from a word document
# adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19503654/284111
# It is not ideal, but good enough
function Extract-Text([string]$fileName) {

  #Generate random temporary file name for text extaction from .docx
  $tempFileName = [Guid]::NewGuid().Guid

  #Extract document xml into a variable ($text)
  $entry = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($fileName).GetEntry("word/document.xml")
  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($entry,$tempFileName)
  $text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($tempFileName)
  Remove-Item $tempFileName

  #Remove actual xml tags and leave the text behind
  $text = $text -replace '</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " "
  $text = $text -replace '</w:r></w:p>', "`r`n"
  $text = $text -replace "<[^>]*>",""

  return $text
}

$fileList = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\SearchFiles" -Include *.docx -Force -recurse
# Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/36023783/284111
$fileList | 
  Foreach-Object {[regex]::matches((Extract-Text $_), '(?<=[A-Za-z]{3}\s*(?:-|–)\s*)\d{4}')} | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty captures | 
  Sort-Object value -Descending | 
  Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty value
```

The main idea behind this is not to monkey around the COM api for Word, but instead just try and extract the text information from the document manually.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your generous help. It did find the highest number and out put it to screen. I am happy -  it does what I need it to - which is find the highest number from the documents -  and that's good enough for me now. It did give some errors, but considering I have no experience  - I will learn more about this and slowly build up my skills - thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the highest number is first isolate it using a regex and then sort and select the first item. Something like this:

```
[regex]::matches($objSelection, '(?<=[A-Z]{3}\s*-\s*)\d{4}')  `
  | Select -ExpandProperty captures `
  | sort value -Descending `
  | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty value `
  | Add-Content outfile.txt
```

I think the problem you are having with your regex is that your example data contains spaces around the dash in the code which haven't allowed for in your pattern.

Comment: Hi Dave -Thank you for your help  - I have done this $list = gci "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Search\" -Include *.docx -Force -recurse
foreach ($foo in $list) {$objWord = New-Object -ComObjectword.application$objWord.Visible = $False
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("$foo")$objSelection = $objWord.Selection [regex]::matches($objSelection, '(?<=[A-Z]{3}\s*\s*)\d{4}')  ` | Select -ExpandProperty captures `
 | sort value -Descending `  | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty value ` | Add-Content outfile.txt } -  I must have done it wrong  -+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Thank you Dave - I will use your code  - to add to my powershell tools :)